# TinCan course not recording completion in cornerstone LMS

Tags: cornerstone, articulate-storyline, xapi

Trying to upload a articulate 360 xapi published course into cornerstone LMS. As first step Published the course with basic settings reporting to LMS and tracking on passing the quiz at 80%.

At Content level there are 2 checkboxes in Cornerstone LMS (1.)IsScoring and (2. )Use TinCAn verbs for completion.

1. When unchecked both the course marks complete upon launch.
2. When Checked both or either the course does not mark complete upon passing the quiz.

In debug mode can see the statements generated with passed verb.. Please guide on this. How can I get the completion tracked. Am I missing some setting in Cornerstone LMS.